# How to fix memory leak in AFNetworking 3.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm testing app in the instruments so below code getting memory leak. Please tell me how to fix it.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

Comment: Ya there are some memory leaks in AFNetworking framework you can nil "manager" object at the end of the method. So when app request it again then it will create the new one again

Comment: @suhas Please check my answer. And kindly give response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i am late to the party, but answering for those who bumped into this. This is the expected behaviour. when you are done with the session you need to call this `invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:`.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

__weak typeof(self) welf = self;
[self.manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
    // progress block
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    //Invalidate Session here
    [welf.manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];
    // stuff needed to be done
}];
```

Comment: [welf.manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];  what is welf here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
         self.manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
});
```